# what is sizeof data types in 8 bit microcontroller?

Tags: c

What is the size of data type in an 8-bit microcontroller like int, char, float, double?

Also, I wanted to know why 32 bit microcontroller data types have fixed size?

Comment: It depends on the compiler. And where did you read that _32 bit microcontroller data types have fixed size_? Your question is pretty unclear, please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to write a program for the platform you are interested in that prints out the sizes and then run it.

Comment: Reading documentation helps too. Because sometimes you can control certain things, such as the size of `float` vs `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of an `int`, `float`, etc, is not determined by the microcontroller.      The complier choses.  Size is influenced by the the native processor width, yet the ultimate decision is a compiler choice with limitations by the standard like an `int` must be *at least* 16-bit.

"32 bit microcontroller data types have fixed size?" is not a truism.

The size of an `int` is readily found with

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

printf("int bit-size: %zu\n", sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT);
// or indirectly with
printf("int min/max values: %d/%d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
```